# Problem consuming RESTful WCF web service with php curl

Tags: php, wcf, curl, rest

I am having problems consuming a WCF web service (PaySimple's v3.00 API) using php curl. I am trying to post an xml payload to the service and I keep getting a 400 - Bad Request error. When I using Firefox's Poster add-on, I can post the very same payload and I get the expected response - 200 OK with an XML response containing the required response. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        $payload = $createPayload();
        $length = strlen($payload);
        $headers = array("Expect:");
        if($isPost)
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
            $headers[] = "Content-length: $length";
        }
        else {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
        }
        if($requestType == 'xml')
        {
            $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset: utf-8';
            $headers[] = 'Accept: application/xml';
        }
        else {
            $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json; charset: utf-8';
            $headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
        }            
        $headers[] = "Connection: close";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        //debugging
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
        $fh = fopen('curl_debug.txt', 'w');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fh);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);            
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

$payload contains the following value:

```
<AddCustomer xmlns="http://api.paysimple.com"><userkey>APIUser1989</userkey><apikey>pxTbp4F6y7JuaMu36qazEw51JiqUA7lGme0j62r3UeQyNojvEfpNo7tn4pLq0yEULHz5KykHWV6AjNQJEyskCw0tXSKZ0vcP5mCynh1IgfQEH4NdXRkXeMNAGEdx6Ee0</apikey><customer xmlns="http://api.paysimple.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><ApiConsumerData/><PsReferenceId>0</PsReferenceId><AltEmail>testemail@paysimpledev.com</AltEmail><AltPhone/><BillingAddress1>TestBillingAddress1</BillingAddress1><BillingAddress2/><BillingCity>TestBillingCity</BillingCity><BillingCountryCode/><BillingPostalCode>80202</BillingPostalCode><BillingState>6</BillingState><CompanyName>TestCompany</CompanyName><CreatedOn>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreatedOn><Email>testemail@paysimpledev.com</Email><Fax/><FirstName>TestFirstName</FirstName><LastModified>0001-01-01T00:00:00</LastModified><LastName>TestLastName</LastName><MiddleName/><Notes/><Phone>5551234567</Phone><ShippingAddress1/><ShippingAddress2/><ShippingCity/><ShippingCountryCode/><ShippingPostalCode/><ShippingSameAsBilling>true</ShippingSameAsBilling><ShippingState>0</ShippingState><WebSite/></customer></AddCustomer>
```

Here's what shows up in curl_debug.txt:

- About to connect() to sandbox-api.paysimple.com port 443 (#0)
- Trying 165.193.50.51... * connected
- Connected to sandbox-api.paysimple.com (165.193.50.51) port 443 (#0)
- successfully set certificate verify locations:
- CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
- SSL connection using RC4-MD5
- Server certificate:
- subject: C=US; ST=Colorado; L=Denver; O=PaySimple, Inc.; OU=PaySimple; CN=*.paysimple.com
- start date: 2010-05-04 00:00:00 GMT
- expire date: 2011-06-29 23:59:59 GMT
- issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-3
- SSL certificate verify ok.

POST /3.00/paysimpleapi.svc/xml/listcustomers HTTP/1.1
Host: sandbox-api.paysimple.com
Content-length: 1153
Content-Type: text/xml; charset: utf-8
Accept: application/xml
Connection: close

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
 Connection: close
 Date: Fri, 27 Aug 2010 11:07:21 GMT
 Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
 X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
 Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=oxpese454u4rr3552evybjue; path=/; HttpOnly
 Cache-Control: private
 Content-Length: 0

Closing connection #0

F1! F1!

Comment: By the way, the it works fine when I send a GET request with no parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably in one of these:

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset: utf-8
Accept: application/xml
```

Try text/xml or application/xml for both, try uppercase UTF-8. Try to send the same headers as Firefox.

Comment: Tried both. Still fails.. besides, this can't be the problem since I am using Poster to send the exact same headers. My guess is it's something to do with curl, I just can't figure out what it is.

Comment: In fact, when I change the Content-Type to application/xml, I get the following: The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are 'Xml', 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been configured on the binding. See the documentation of WebContentTypeMapper for more details.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:
...

Comment: After some more tinkering around, I discovered that your first answer was actually the closest to correct. Indeed the source of the problem was 
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset: utf-8  
Removing the charset: utf-8 part did it. Strangely, it works with that part when sending GET requests? Could it be a bug in curl's implementation or on the WCF side?

Answer (score 0):

Your POST's Content-Type should probably be application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data, and not application/xml

Comment: Unlikely. He is not submitting a form, and the posted data is not urlencoded.

Comment: It's not about sending a form, but about telling the server what to expect. And servers expect either application/x-www-form-urlencoded, or multipart/form-data. The first for regular key/value pairs, the second to upload binary data.

It's the first thing i look for when getting a 400 error

Comment: Thanks, Sjon. Changing this to either of those causes the same error as I have put as the one that Sjoerd's suggestion about the text/xml and application/xml causes.

Answer (score 0):

Tash

Post to https://sandbox-api.paysimple.com/3.00/PaysimpleApi.svc/xml/addcustomer http/1.1

use header:
Content-length: 1262
Content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/xml
Method: invokeMethod
UserAgent: PaySimple
Host: sandbox-api.paysimple.com

Try request
SandboxMelody
qUWzSPxkcxDR6RJiR2ypzbznV4m6jva5N8kaosnNqQJYqNTGcVouWhKbN5NPGiZxJdmx2QnapYNcwq1bjtfmGwLhBcdMT6x3z7IdPVYA3H7HDBUqwW6eJDyaf8dhKqr0
0
1122 Boogie Woogie Avenue#6City
801116CompanyName99999
0001-01-01T00:00:00w@w.comTestUser0001-01-01T00:00:00
LastNameThis is a new customer...from Fiddler3035551212
1122 Boogie Woogie Avenue#5City
80111true6

USE ADDCUSTOMER in both post url and request body